# Mathematica is getting slow when repeatedly starting an external program

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I found a strange phenomenon that ***Mathematica*** is getting slow when I repeatedly started an external program by using **ReadList**. For example, the following code will display a significant increase of CPU time for each 'ls' command (my platform is OS X):

```
data = Table[Timing[ReadList["!ls"]], {100000}][[All, 1]];
ListPlot[data]
```

This phenomenon seems ubiquitous for the other external programs. Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this speed down?